# Ommit lines containing a specific pattern or string in a tail -f output

Tags: shell, unix, tail

Everything is in the title I think. Here's a little more info : I write a lot of data to a log file that I want to `tail -f` on a separate screen. I want all the data written to the file but I don't need it all in the `tail -f` output. For example instead of having

```
= 2016-11-10 17:11:06 ==========================================================
PONG not logged
================================================================================
= 2016-11-10 17:11:07 ==========================================================
PONG Stan
================================================================================
= 2016-11-10 17:11:07 ==========================================================
MatchMaking { id: '20',
  email: 'stanley@beatme.io',
  gender: 'male',
  fbid: '167198360375634',
  console: '5',
  game: '5',
  beatmeid: 'Stan',
  fairplay: 100,
  victories: 32,
  wallet: 11950 }
================================================================================
= 2016-11-10 17:11:07 ==========================================================
User  Stan Started MatchMaking
================================================================================
MatchMaking : user Stan successfully joined
user 20 resumed MatchmakingActivity
= 2016-11-10 17:11:08 ==========================================================
PONG not logged
================================================================================
================================================================================
= 2016-11-10 17:11:08 ==========================================================
PONG kejjimourad
================================================================================
= 2016-11-10 17:11:09 ==========================================================
PONG not logged
================================================================================
Matched players Kijey and Stan
tryStartGame 5-5
areYouReady [ 274, 20 ]
Matched 1 in one round
= 2016-11-10 17:11:10 ==========================================================
PONG not logged
================================================================================
= 2016-11-10 17:11:10 ==========================================================
Notification sent { success: true,
  data: [Object] }
================================================================================
= 2016-11-10 17:11:10 ==========================================================
Notification sent { success: true,
  data:
   { multicast_id: 8703116803504844000,
     success: 1,
     failure: 0,
     canonical_ids: 0,
     results: [ [Object] ] } }
================================================================================
= 2016-11-10 17:11:10 ==========================================================
PONG kejjimourad
================================================================================
= 2016-11-10 17:11:11 ==========================================================
PONG Stan
================================================================================
```

I wish I could ommit all the lines that contain "PONG" (and if possible one line above and one line under) so that I have only the relevant information, ie :

```
= 2016-11-10 17:11:07 ==========================================================
MatchMaking { id: '20',
  email: 'stanley@beatme.io',
  gender: 'male',
  fbid: '167198360375634',
  console: '5',
  game: '5',
  beatmeid: 'Stan',
  fairplay: 100,
  victories: 32,
  wallet: 11950 }
================================================================================
= 2016-11-10 17:11:07 ==========================================================
User  Stan Started MatchMaking
================================================================================
MatchMaking : user Stan successfully joined
user 20 resumed MatchmakingActivity
Matched players Kijey and Stan
tryStartGame 5-5
areYouReady [ 274, 20 ]
Matched 1 in one round
= 2016-11-10 17:11:10 ==========================================================
Notification sent { success: true,
  data: [Object] }
================================================================================
= 2016-11-10 17:11:10 ==========================================================
Notification sent { success: true,
  data:
   { multicast_id: 8703116803504844000,
     success: 1,
     failure: 0,
     canonical_ids: 0,
     results: [ [Object] ] } }
================================================================================
```

Comment: Just do `tail -f file | grep -v PONG`

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman ! I tried this and added `-A1 -B1` to ommit also one line before and one line after but instead it shows only the lines I want to ommit, do you have any idea how I can ommit the PONG lines along with one line after and one line before them ?